# File download API windows 7 phone SDK , cordova

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, cordova, cordova-3

Trying to use file transfer API on phonegap(cordova) windows 7 , cant find how to retrieve a file from a remote server or location and store it . I am trying it on emulator , suggest some solutions